# USB malfunction and rooting of my Samsung SIII (GT-I9305)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, usb

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII (GT-I9305), and here are my problem(s). It can't be detected by PC via USB (not showing on device manager, odin, kies, not even charging) but it is charging when connected thru a charger. Is the micro-usb port damaged? I don't think so because but it can detect my flash drive via USB OTG. I already tried reinstalling correct drivers, tried different cables, tried different USB port, factory reset both from settings and recovery menu.

How can I fix this?

Also, I'm wondering if I can still attain root access/permission even without USB connection but thru terminal emulator?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like either only one or even both central connectors of your phone's micro-USB port are broken. Charging only uses the outer ones which let's you use the charger.
If I assume that by *detecting* your flash drive you haven't accessed it, then it's this.

You are able to root your device (I got the same one) without a USB connection using *TowelRoot, FramaRoot or a flashable .zip* ([visit xda-developers for more info(1)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/development-i9305) or [(2)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/help-i9305))

Comment: thank you for responding sir, but it is not charging if connected to the computer, it only charge when connected directly to a charger. towel root does not work also sir, and even if i have a flashable zip, I won't be able to flash it thru a stock recovery.

Comment: You are able to flash it through stock recovery. I did it before and it's working now as well as it has in the past (boot into recovery and select flash update.zip). Whatever you did, TowelRoot or FramaRoot, both worked for me.

Comment: wow! I will try sir! Just to clarify, I can flash a flashable zip of superSU? or CWM?

Comment: Root + SuperSU. You don't need CWM to root your device. The stock recovery is enough and will allow the installation (at least on Android 4.3)

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try, should i rename the zip to update.zip? am I right? I hope this will not give an error "permission denied"

Comment: Depending on the revision of your recovery I suggest you to rename it and place it in the root directory of your internal storage.